# All standardized random variables follow standard normal?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

We know that if $X\sim\mathcal N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ then $Z=(X-\mu)/\sigma\sim\mathcal N(0,1)$.

I was wondering. If $X$ follows any distribution, will $(X-\mu)/\sigma\sim\mathcal N(0,1)$ as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  Only a tiny tiny rare sliver of all probability distributions are normal ones.  In the space of all probability distributions the normal ones are real rarities.

What you suggest results in a random variable with zero mean and variance $1$, but nothing more than that.  If $X$ is bounded then your $(X-\mu)/\sigma$ will be bounded.  If your $X$ is discrete then your $(X-\mu)/\sigma$  will be discrete. If your $X$ is bimodal or skewed, your $(X-\mu)/\sigma$  will be, too.  None of these descriptions hold for any $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ or for $N(0,1)$.

If you have learned about uniform, binomial, Poisson, Cauchy, exponential, gamma, or chi-squared random variables, they are all counterexamples to what you suggest.

Comment: But as normal distribution is a limiting case of binomial....We take a binomial random variable then subtract it to it's mean I.e.np and then divide whole by its standard deviation I.e. sqare root of npq......N this follow standard normal(0,1). What about that?

Comment: A so called "standardized binomial" rv is approximately normal but not exactly normal.  Sometimes the approximation is good enough for this purpose and sometimes not good enough for that purpose.

Comment: Got it.thanks for ur time@kimchi lover.